# Using JSTL to get a dropdown list from enum class into JSP

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, enums, jstl

I am new to JSTL and Spring Framework. I am trying to populate a dropdown list in a spring form using JSTL tags. The values are coming from an `Enum class`. But for some reason I am getting a blank list. There are no error messages.

ENUM Class:

```
package edu.bnu.fyp.stp.constants;
public enum TutorType {
    Home_Tutor ("Home Tutor"), Online_Tutor ("Online Tutor");
    private String tutorType;
    private TutorType(String s){
        tutorType = s;
    }
    public String getTutorType() {
        return tutorType;
    }
    public void setTutorType(String tutorType) {
        this.tutorType = tutorType;
    }
}
```

Controller Class:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/studentdashboard/requirement")
public String showPostRequirement(Model model){
    List <TutorType> tutorTypes = tutorTypes = new ArrayList<TutorType (Arrays.asList(TutorType.values()));
    model.addAttribute("TutorType", TutorType.values());
    return "Requirement";
}
```

JSP

```
<select name="${status.expression}" name="TutorType" id="TutorType">
     <option value=""></option>
     <items="${TutorType}" var="option">
     <option value="${option}">
         <co:out value="${option.tutorType}"></co:out>
     </option>
     </>
</select>
```

Please let me know where I am doing this wrong? Thank you

Comment: Why not using Spring MVC's own `<form:select><form:options>` tags?

Comment: It would help if you did a `<c:forEach>` instead of that no-name tag. It would also help if you actually added `TutorType` to the `model`.

Comment: That was a Typo, I did added the TutorType to the model. Just updated the description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited the jsp code and it is working now.

```
<select name="tutorType" id="tutorType">
    <option value=""></option>
    <co:forEach items="${tutorType}" var="value">
       <option>${value}</option>
    </co:forEach>
    </>
</select>
```